# Is this grammatically correct? (wearing a demeanor)

Tags: word-usage, collocations, metaphors

Can you say about someone that he wears his demeanor?

This is the specific sentence:
"I was wearing my usual peevish demeanor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's grammatically correct.

---

"**Wear**" can mean:

> [**to bear** or have in **one's aspect** or appearance: to wear a smile; to
>   wear an air of triumph.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wear)

So, wearing a *characteristic of personality* is perfectly fine.

Comment: I agree with segre's answer that "showing" or "displaying" demeanor is more common but if you **really** want to say "wearing" to sound more creative, there is absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

"Showing" or "displaying" would be more natural than "wearing". Imagine a peacock's tail. It wears it all the time, but doesn't necessarily display it.